# Accidentally ran the Paypal checkout api too many times because of ReactJS. The site won't load anymore

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use PayPal Checkout on my E-Commerce store, however when I tried to make something work involving the @paypal/react-paypal-js library, I accidentally ran it about a 100 times. Now I'm blocked and the request to paypal.com just won't load. How do I resolve this?

I tried to checkout with PayPal Checkout ran it accidentally into a loop and got blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different IP address or wait awhile.

Meanwhile ensure you won't trigger the same loop again.